# Rectangles in a ListView

Tags: qt, qml

I have a cutom QML object `Myrect.qml`:

```
import QtQuick 2.0

Item
{
    property alias color: theRect.color;
    property string title: "default";

    Rectangle
    {
        id: theRect;

        Text
        {
            text: title;
        }

        width: 60;
        height: 80;
    }
}
```

And there is my main code `main.qml`:

```
import QtQuick 2.9
import QtQuick.Window 2.2
import QtQuick.Controls 2.2

Window 
{
    visible: true
    width: 600
    height: 400
    title: qsTr("Model example")

    ListModel
    {
        id:  myModel;

        ListElement { name: "Apple"; col: "green"; }
        ListElement { name: "Orange"; col: "orange"; }
        ListElement { name: "Banana"; col: "yellow"; }
    }

    ListView
    {
        model: myModel;
        delegate: myRectComp;
    }

    Component
    {
        id: myRectComp;

        Myrect
        {
            color: col;
            title: name;
        }
    }
}
```

What I am trying to accomplish is such effect:

[image]

`a` is the distance from the left corner of the parent, `b` is the distance between elements in the list. So far my code stacks all rectangles on top each other:

[image]

I am not sure how to move further from this point. Also, eventually the application could be rotated and the rectangles should rotate as well- the row will become a column. I wonder wither such functionality is readily available in QML?

How to evenly distribute the members in a row and in a column?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modify **orientation**, **spacing** and **position** properties to get the layout horizontally with space. To change the view to Vertical set the [orientation](https://doc-snapshots.qt.io/qt5-5.9/qml-qtquick-listview.html#orientation-prop) property as **Qt.Vertical** .

```
ListView
    {
        model: myModel;
        delegate: myRectComp;
        x: 100 // your 'a' start 'x' position for Listview
        width: parent.width
        height: parent.height
        spacing: 100 // 'b' space between elements
        orientation:  Qt.Horizontal
    }
```

Below is the output with above Listview properties

[image]

Comment: Exactly what I needed. Thank you.